# overflow menu change the listview data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite, pull-to-refresh

I am new in android using custom based adopter in my listview  my all data is coming from database SQLite which have different table in my database my problem is that I want to change my listview data from overflow menu in overflow menu I have different radio button if any user selected any particular radio if it checks the data listview must be changed but problem that is not refreshing here is my code and picture what actually I want to say?

[image: here is my overflow menu]

if any user clicked 
on kings James version my database table name change into t_kjv which exists in my database  user clicked on an American standard 
the table name change into t_asv
but the problem is that database listview not refresh and it will not take any effect on my listview

here is my cod my default i set my table name is t_kjv; when activity is load

**here is my code**

```
   package bible.swordof.God;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.yokkomi.commons.preference.seekbar.SeekBarPreference;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import es.dmoral.toasty.Toasty;

public class ALLVERSE extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    private ListView mylistview;
    private ArrayList<String> versenumber;
    private ArrayList<String> verselist;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> refernce;
    private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private int booknumber;
    private int chapternumber;
    private String bookname;
    public int versepos;
    private TextView booknametitle;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int result;
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    BaseAdapter baseAdapter;

    SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh;



    LinearLayout linearLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();

        }
        super.onDestroy();

    }


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_allverse);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        booknametitle = findViewById(R.id.bookname);

        linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.nightmode);
        final Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        booknumber = mIntent.getIntExtra("Boooknumber", 0);
        chapternumber = mIntent.getIntExtra("Chapternumber", 0);
        bookname = mIntent.getStringExtra("Bookname");
        versepos = mIntent.getIntExtra("versenumber", 1);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("versenumber", versepos);
        editor.commit();







        booknametitle.setText(bookname.toString() + "   " + chapternumber);


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        toolbar.setTitle(bookname+":"+chapternumber);


        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        setData("t_kjv");

        mylistview = findViewById(R.id.mylistview);


   baseAdapter = new BaseAdopter(this, versenumber, id, verselist, refernce);


        mylistview.setAdapter(baseAdapter);


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (DefaultSettings.autospeak(ALLVERSE.this)) {
                    speakOut(verselist.get(versepos - 1));
                }
                //speak after 1000ms
            }
        }, 1000);

        mylistview.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(versepos) - 1);


    }





    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fullsepak, menu);
        return true;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
       else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.fullspeak) {

speakfull(verselist.toString());

       }
       else  if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.kjv){
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);

            setData("t_kjv");

            baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
        else  if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.asv){
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            setData("t_asv");

        }
        else  if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.darby){
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);

        }

        else  if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.bbe){
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            setData("t_bbe");

            Toast.makeText(this, "change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }



        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private void setData(String tablename) {
        versenumber = new ArrayList<>();
        verselist = new ArrayList<>();
        refernce = new ArrayList<>();
        id = new ArrayList<>();

        mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT id, v, t from "+tablename+" where b="  + booknumber + " AND c=" + chapternumber + ";", new String[]{});
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                    versenumber.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    verselist.add(cursor.getString(2));

                    refernce.add(bookname + " " + chapternumber);

                }

                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (baseAdapter  != null) {
                baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Fragment fragment;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.home) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (id == R.id.favoruite) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Favourite.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.setting) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.alert) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Reminder.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    private void speakOut(String text) {
        DefaultSettings.speed(this);

        textToSpeech.setPitch(DefaultSettings.pitchvalue);

        textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(DefaultSettings.speedvalue);


        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        if (textToSpeech != null) {
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();

        }
    }

    private void speakfull(String text) {
        ///
        Pattern re = Pattern.compile("[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['\"]?\\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['\"]?(?=\\s|$)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
        Matcher reMatcher = re.matcher(text);
        /////
        int position=0 ;
        int sizeOfChar= text.length();
        String testStri= text.substring(position,sizeOfChar);
        while(reMatcher.find()) {
            String temp = "";

            try {

                temp = testStri.substring(text.lastIndexOf(reMatcher.group()), text.indexOf(reMatcher.group()) + reMatcher.group().length());


                  DefaultSettings.speed(this);
                textToSpeech.setPitch(DefaultSettings.pitchvalue);

                textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(DefaultSettings.speedvalue);


                textToSpeech.speak(temp, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                temp = testStri.substring(0, testStri.length());


                textToSpeech.speak(temp, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                break;


            }
        }
    }

            @Override
            public void onInit ( int status){


                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

                    int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                    // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

                    // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
                    } else {

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should be like this:

```
public class ALLVERSE extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

  private ListView mylistview;
  private ArrayList<String> versenumber = new ArrayList<>();
  private ArrayList<String> verselist = new ArrayList<>();
  private ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
  private ArrayList<String> refernce = new ArrayList<>();
  private DatabaseHelper mDBHelper;
  private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
  private int booknumber;
  private int chapternumber;
  private String bookname;
  public int versepos;
  private TextView booknametitle;
  TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
  private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
  int result;
  private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
  BaseAdapter baseAdapter;

  SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh;


  LinearLayout linearLayout;


  @Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    if (textToSpeech != null) {
      textToSpeech.stop();
      textToSpeech.shutdown();

    }
    super.onDestroy();

  }


  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_allverse);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    booknametitle = findViewById(R.id.bookname);

    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.nightmode);
    final Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    booknumber = mIntent.getIntExtra("Boooknumber", 0);
    chapternumber = mIntent.getIntExtra("Chapternumber", 0);
    bookname = mIntent.getStringExtra("Bookname");
    versepos = mIntent.getIntExtra("versenumber", 1);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("DATA", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("versenumber", versepos);
    editor.commit();

    booknametitle.setText(bookname.toString() + "   " + chapternumber);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitle(bookname + ":" + chapternumber);

    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mylistview = findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
    setData("t_kjv");

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (DefaultSettings.autospeak(ALLVERSE.this)) {
          speakOut(verselist.get(versepos - 1));
        }
        //speak after 1000ms
      }
    }, 1000);

    mylistview.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(versepos) - 1);


  }


  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fullsepak, menu);
    return true;


  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
      onBackPressed();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.fullspeak) {

      speakfull(verselist.toString());

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.kjv) {
      if (item.isChecked()) {
        item.setChecked(false);
      } else {
        item.setChecked(true);
      }

      setData("t_kjv");

      baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.asv) {
      if (item.isChecked()) {
        item.setChecked(false);
      } else {
        item.setChecked(true);
      }
      setData("t_asv");

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.darby) {
      if (item.isChecked()) {
        item.setChecked(false);
      } else {
        item.setChecked(true);
      }

    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bbe) {
      if (item.isChecked()) {
        item.setChecked(false);
      } else {
        item.setChecked(true);
      }
      setData("t_bbe");

      Toast.makeText(this, "change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }


  private void setData(String tablename) {
    versenumber.clear();
    verselist.clear();
    id.clear();
    refernce.clear();

    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    mDb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(
        "SELECT id, v, t from " + tablename + " where b=" + booknumber + " AND c=" + chapternumber
            + ";", new String[]{});
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
          id.add(cursor.getString(0));
          versenumber.add(cursor.getString(1));
          verselist.add(cursor.getString(2));

          refernce.add(bookname + " " + chapternumber);

        }

        while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      if (baseAdapter != null) {
        baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      } else {

        baseAdapter = new BaseAdapter(this, versenumber, id, verselist, refernce);
        mylistview.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    Fragment fragment;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.home) {

      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.favoruite) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Favourite.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.setting) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.alert) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Reminder.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }

  private void speakOut(String text) {
    DefaultSettings.speed(this);

    textToSpeech.setPitch(DefaultSettings.pitchvalue);

    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(DefaultSettings.speedvalue);

    textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    if (textToSpeech != null) {
      textToSpeech.stop();
      textToSpeech.shutdown();

    }
  }

  private void speakfull(String text) {
    ///
    Pattern re = Pattern
        .compile("[^.!?\\s][^.!?]*(?:[.!?](?!['\"]?\\s|$)[^.!?]*)*[.!?]?['\"]?(?=\\s|$)",
            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.COMMENTS);
    Matcher reMatcher = re.matcher(text);
    /////
    int position = 0;
    int sizeOfChar = text.length();
    String testStri = text.substring(position, sizeOfChar);
    while (reMatcher.find()) {
      String temp = "";

      try {

        temp = testStri.substring(text.lastIndexOf(reMatcher.group()),
            text.indexOf(reMatcher.group()) + reMatcher.group().length());

        DefaultSettings.speed(this);
        textToSpeech.setPitch(DefaultSettings.pitchvalue);

        textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(DefaultSettings.speedvalue);

        textToSpeech.speak(temp, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);


      } catch (Exception e) {
        temp = testStri.substring(0, testStri.length());

        textToSpeech.speak(temp, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;


      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

      int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

      // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

      // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

      if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
          || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
      } else {

      }

    } else {
      Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: i also want to set default name in my table so when activity is load set default table name

Comment: `setData("t_bbe");` this calls the setData method with your default tablename in onCreate. I don't think this should be a problem. Upvote the answer if helped and accept if worked.

Comment: it will not effect on my list view  here code     else  if(item.getItemId() ==R.id.bbe){
            if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
            else item.setChecked(true);
            setData("t_bbe");

            Toast.makeText(this, "change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Comment: Can you try with the method I have added? I have updated that again.

Comment: yes i tried your method i will update my code you can check now

Comment: in oncreate method set data work fine but also i want change using overflow menu

Comment: I have pasted the whole class here. You can directly use that. It will surely work.

Comment: i also need to    implement     SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh;listner?

Comment: Vote up and Accept the answer if worked.  For pullToRefresh ask a new question.

Comment: where you from may i join on facebook or whatsapp?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you only query Cursor at `onCreate`.

You need to call `setData` from `onOptionsItemSelected`. Also you may need to call `baseAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` after swapping items in adapter.